# Find out what caused machine reboot

Tags: linux, rhel

I have a RHEL VM that restarted at 18:30 yesterday.

I want to know what restarted the machine.

I went through `/var/log/messages`, cant find any event that could restart the machine.

Cant find any command that will reboot the machine in `lastcomm`.

No cronjob set that could do this.

No hardware issue in dmesg that could trigger this.

Nothing found in `/var/log/kernel` as well.

What else can I do/check to find out what triggered system reboot?

P.S:

One strange thing I noticed in `/var/logs/messages` file is this;

```
May 18 18:31:06 ABC-DEF rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="3360" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May 18 18:30:29 ABC-DEF journal: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 3.9G, trying to leave 4.0G free of 39.2G available → current limit 3.9G).
```

Notice the timestamp.

Comment: You're sure it wasn't an environmental power failure?

Comment: This machine is a VM. Other VM's are OK. and the machine came back up within 90 seconds.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a VM, you will need to look at the hypervisor and investigate its logs.  If the VM was terminated abruptly, the guest has no way to log a cause for that because it is just gone.